# Struct Pointer giving already allocated address on 'new' call?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am using a struct `Node` in a templated class `MyQueue`.

After debugging for several hours, I can see that in the `stutter()` member function, I call `new` and the `Node` pointer returned appears to be already in use, and it goes into an infinite loop  I've tried `typedef`, and using structures for the struct as well with no luck.

During debugging, it became clear that when attempting to create new Nodes to insert into the linked list, the program was just reusing memory already allocated for other Nodes.

My header and implementation are below, with some annotation on behavior I've noticed on the implementation of `stutter()`.

```
#pragma once

template <typename elemtype>
class MyQueue
{
public:
    MyQueue();
    ~MyQueue();
    void enqueue(elemtype item);
    elemtype dequeue();
    bool isEmpty();
    void stutter();
    void unStutter();

private:
    int size;
    struct Node{
        elemtype data;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
};
```

myqueue.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "myqueue.h"

template <typename elemtype>
MyQueue<elemtype>::MyQueue()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}     

template <typename elemtype>
MyQueue<elemtype>::~MyQueue()
{
    Node *next;
    while (head != nullptr){
        next = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
}   

template <typename elemtype>
void MyQueue<elemtype>::enqueue(elemtype item){
    Node *tmp = new Node();
    tmp->data = item;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    if (isEmpty()){
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }else{
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    size++;
}

template <typename elemtype>
bool MyQueue<elemtype>::isEmpty(){
    return (size==0) ? true : false;
}

template <typename elemtype>
elemtype MyQueue<elemtype>::dequeue(){

     Node* old = head;
     elemtype item = head->data;
     head = head->next;
     size--;
     delete old;
     return item;
}

template <typename elemtype>
void MyQueue<elemtype>::stutter(){
    //function is trying to repeat every element in a linked list
    Node *insertedNode;  //if I do the full new declaration here, it gives me a new address, but I can't get another as I loop
    if (size ==0 ){
        return;
    }
    Node *current = head; //current is meant to be an iterator
    while(current != nullptr){
        insertedNode = new Node();  //this is setting the value of the ptr to = head --- no idea why.
      //  *insertedNode = *current; //Removed based on comments             
        insertedNode->data = current->data; //Updated to make proper assignment
        insertedNode->next = current->next; //Updated to make proper assignment
        current->next = insertedNode; //insert new node
        current = insertedNode->next; //move on skipping new node
        size++;
    }
}

template <typename elemtype>
void MyQueue<elemtype>::unStutter(){
    if (size ==0) {return;}
    Node *current = head;
    Node *trash = head;
    while(current->next != nullptr){
        if (current->data == current->next->data){
            trash = current->next;
            current->next = current->next->next;
            delete trash;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

I'm completely stumped at this point.  I thought I was getting a good grasp on pointers, but I just don't understand the behavior in this case.

**Update including main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myqueue.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Testing Queue implementation" << std::endl;
    MyQueue<int> q;
    q.enqueue(1);
    q.enqueue(2);
    q.enqueue(3);
    q.stutter();
    int tmpi;
    while (!q.isEmpty()){
        tmpi = q.dequeue();
        std::cout << tmpi << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "myqueue.cpp"` - don't include C++ source files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The OP does set `insertedNode->next` to be equal to `current->next`, by way of `*insertedNode = *current`

Comment: The code you show looks OK to me. To the extent there is a problem, it probably lies in the code you haven't shown. It would be best if you can demonstrate a [mcve].

Comment: [The code shown works fine](https://ideone.com/cSAdyn). However, one thing I do notice is that `stutter()` does not update `tail` after it duplicates the `tail` node. Since the duplicate follows the old `tail`, you need to make the last `insertedNode` become the new `tail`.

Comment: the only time I've seen this happen was when a student was deleting the thing they just allocated, followed by another allocation. I don't suppose you have an iterator type with a user-defined destructor?

Comment: [I can easily break your code](https://ideone.com/ZCffRB).  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code to include all of the implementation and main file I am using to test right now.  @NeilButterworth- removing the include of the implementation has caused an undefined reference to the <int> instantiation.  #include after the header was the only way I knew to fix that, is there a better practice?

Comment: Does anything change if you compile with all warnings turned on?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure still why this was the behavior- I was able to solve the problem with @neilbutterworth 's comment around changing how I was doing the template class instantiation.  I put the class I needed explicitly at the bottom of the implementation and it immediately started working.

Comment: Unless you can show why what you did fixed the issue  then your "solution " is no solution.  All you did was to change the executable to a point where the bug is moved to another part of the program.  More than likely, you have corrupted memory.